# Crodova vk plugin does not work [cannot read package name from manifest file]

Tags: cordova-plugins, vk-sdk

After installing https://github.com/akveo/cordova-vk/

cordova plugin add cordova-vk --variable VK_APP_ID=....

It says about adding vksdk_library
 You should add

```
'android.library.reference.2=vksdk_library' to project.properties
```

If add it to my 
platforms\android\project.properties 
as

```
android.library.reference.1=CordovaLib
android.library.reference.2=app
android.library.reference.3=vksdk_library
```

in build time i got error 
* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':vksdk_library'.

> Cannot read packageName from C:\games\cordova\gamename\platforms\android\vksdk_library\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: The file looks like this:     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.vk.sdk"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0">
    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />
        <application>
            <activity android:name="com.vk.sdk.VKOpenAuthActivity" />
        </application>
    </manifest>


If i do not add vksd_library to the project i got nothing happen in  
when i use VkSdk.init('123456')
Maybe i can go without vksdk_library?